# XML check for duplicates

Tags: java, xml

I have been working with the XML files for a couple of days and I've tried to develop a program that checks if in my XML are some english words that have been written more than once.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<VOCABULAR>
    <cuvant>
        <cuvE>to go</cuvE>
        <exE>Where to go?
            Go home!
        </exE>
        <cuvR>a merge</cuvR>
        <exR>Unde mergi?
            Mergi acasa!
        </exR>
    </cuvant>
    <cuvant>
        <cuvE>to listen</cuvE>
        <exE>Listen to me!
            I like to listen classical music
        </exE>
        <cuvR>a asculta</cuvR>
        <exR>Asculta-ma!
            Imi place sa ascult muzica clasica
        </exR>
    </cuvant>
    <cuvant>
        <cuvE>to arrive</cuvE>
        <exE>When do you arrive at home ?</exE>
        <cuvR>a ajung</cuvR>
        <exR>Cand ajungi acasa ?</exR>
    </cuvant>
    <cuvant>
        <cuvE>to go</cuvE>
        <exE>Where to go?
            Go home!
        </exE>
        <cuvR>a merge</cuvR>
        <exR>Unde mergi?
            Mergi acasa!
        </exR>
    </cuvant>
</VOCABULAR>
```

and my Java code:

```
public class Cuvant {

    public String cuvR;
    public String exR;
    public String cuvE;
    public String exE;

}

class ParsareVocabular {

    static XMLStreamReader reader;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws XMLStreamException{

        List<Cuvant> al = null;
        Cuvant cuvCrt = null;
        String continutTag = null;
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("vocabular.xml")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(reader.hasNext()){

            int event = reader.next();

            switch(event){

                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                    if("VOCABULAR".equals(reader.getLocalName()))
                        al=new ArrayList<Cuvant>();
                    else if("cuvant".equals(reader.getLocalName()))
                        cuvCrt = new Cuvant();
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    continutTag = reader.getText().trim();
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    switch (reader.getLocalName()) {
                        case "cuvant":
                            al.add(cuvCrt);
                            break;
                        case "cuvR":
                            cuvCrt.cuvR = continutTag;
                            break;
                        case "exR":
                            cuvCrt.exR = continutTag;
                            break;
                        case "cuvE":
                            cuvCrt.cuvE = continutTag;
                            break;
                        case "ExE":
                            cuvCrt.exE = continutTag;
                            break;
                    }
                break;
            }
        }

        Iterator<Cuvant> it = al.iterator();
        int diferit = 0;

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Cuvant c = it.next();
            if(c.cuvE.equals(it.next()))
                diferit++;
            //System.out.println(c.cuvE);
        }

        /*for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
            Cuvant c = it.next();

        }*/
        if(diferit==0)
            System.out.println("no duplicates");
        else
            System.out.println("are duplicates");

        System.out.println("Total words in english: "+al.size());
    }
}
```

I searched for a solution but nothing resolved my problem. If you can help me with a suggestion please do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Inside while instruction I don't know if the rest of instructions are correct to check for duplicate English words. If you know how can I do that please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: `<cuvE>to go</cuvE>` and `<exE>Where to go? Go home! </exE>` both contain the words `to go` so is it going be counted as, yes it's repeated?

Comment: only the one between <cuvE> tag, like the first and the last one. That are duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Cuvant c = it.next();
  if (c.cuvE.equals(it.next()))
    diferit++;
  //System.out.println(c.cuvE);
}
```

Problem with this code is you are trying to find duplicates in adjacent elements but your duplicated elements are far apart.

You need to take first element and then match it with all next elements and subsequently take second element and match it with all next element. This way you will be able to find duplicate elements.

**EDIT**

you can use below code to find duplicates for cuvE

```
int diferit = 0;

for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++) {
   Cuvant c = al.get(i);
   for(int j=i+1; j <al.size(); j++) {
      if(c.cuvE.equals(al.get(j).cuvE))
           diferit++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just added code to find duplicate. hope this helps.